# Combining rows in SQL Server against all other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have an table like this:

[image]

And I want to create a select which combines every non-null row against every other value such that I end up with:

[image]

etc, all the way up to 3 - 3 - 3

Can this be done in one select statement?

Comment: I don't get  it. Maybe it helps if you'd show what you've already tried.

Comment: Please describe logic of what number the null shoul dbe repalced by

Comment: I was actually trying with a larger table than this, with 6 columns. The answer below got me to where I needed to go though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with two `CROSS JOIN`'s:

```
DECLARE @tb AS TABLE
(
    column1 INT
    ,column2 INT
    ,column3 INT
);

INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (1, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (2, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (3, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (NULL, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (NULL, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (NULL, 3, NULL);
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (NULL, NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (NULL, NULL, 3);


SELECT tb1.column1, tb2.column2, tb3.column3
FROM @tb tb1
CROSS JOIN @tb AS tb2
CROSS JOIN @tb AS tb3
WHERE tb1.column1 IS NOT NULL
    AND tb2.column2 IS NOT NULL
    AND tb3.column3 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY tb1.column1, tb2.column2, tb3.column3;
```

Comment: did you test this ? It should return 3*3*3=27 rows. This returns 99 rows with a bunch of null values

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, forgot one condition "WHERE tb1.column1 IS NOT NULL;" (edited post)

Comment: so why is full outer join better than a simple join ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do and going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: full outer is actually not needed, normal join will give same results

Comment: @gjvdkamp, thanks for comment! Guess there is not much performance difference between FULL OUTER JOIN vs JOIN, still query look easier to reed the second way

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to combine values that are now on different rows, first you need to seperate them in subqueries (the `with` statements), then you can cross join these (cartesian product) to find all different combinations.

```
 with 
    c1 as (select column1 from table where column1 is not null),
    c2 as (select column2 from table where column2 is not null),
    c3 as (select column3 from table where column3 is not null)
  select *
  from c1, c2, c3 -- no join condition returns all possible combinations
```

Comment: This will only filtr the null values, i believe u have to cross join those 3 tables  (c1,c2,c3) to get the wanted result

Comment: the select at the end does a cross join (there's no join condition)

Comment: This is actually a more elegant looking solution than the one above, thanks!

Comment: Now you get it ;) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use cross join:

```
DECLARE @t table(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
INSERT @t values
(1, null, null),(2, null, null),(3, null, null),
(null, 1, null),(null, 2, null),(null, 3, null),
(null, null, 1),(null, null, 2),(null, null, 3)

SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3 
FROM @t t1
CROSS JOIN @t t2
CROSS JOIN @t t3
WHERE t1.col1 is not null and t2.col2 is not null and t3.col3 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `Cross Join` here. Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1    cola,NULL colb, NULL colc
         UNION
         SELECT 2    cola,NULL colb,NULL colc
         UNION
         SELECT 3    cola,NULL colb,NULL colc
         UNION
         SELECT NULL cola,1    colb,NULL colc
         UNION
         SELECT NULL cola,2    colb,NULL colc
         UNION
         SELECT NULL cola,3    colb,NULL colc
         UNION
         SELECT NULL cola,NULL colb,1    colc
         UNION
         SELECT NULL cola,NULL colb,2    colc
         UNION
         SELECT NULL cola,NULL colb,3    colc)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT a.cola
        FROM   cte a
        WHERE  cola IS NOT NULL) f
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT b.colb
                   FROM   cte b
                   WHERE  colb IS NOT NULL) s
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT c.colc
                   FROM   cte c
                   WHERE  colc IS NOT NULL) T
```